# How do I check if a MediaWiki extension is installed from within another extension?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am currently working on a MediaWiki extension that requires the "Arrays" extension for some features. If the array extension is not installed, my extension should give a friendly warning when trying to use said features.

How do I check if an extension is installed from within another extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice way is `ExtensionRegistry::getInstance()->isLoaded( 'Arrays' )`. This only works for extensions which use [extension registration](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Extension_registration) (which Arrays does). Otherwise, you can just check if some class from that extension can be loaded.

Comment: This tells us whether the extension has been loaded, not whether it exists on the filesystem.

Comment: Why would you care whether or not it exists on the filesystem? If it's not loaded, other extensions relying on it will break, whether the files are present or not.

Comment: The OP may not care, but I do, it's the reason I'm looking at this question. I am using the same configuration file for different wikis with different sets of extensions installed, so I need to make some configuration (such as loading them) conditional on whether they are installed (exist on the filesystem).